# ViewModel is going null in Controller when data is posting through ajax

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am posting the data through ajax from my form but it is going null always.
What i am doing is:-

In my **View Page**:-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#blogForm").submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            alert("YOO");
            debugger;
            var fileInput = $('#authorImage')[0];
            var authorImage = fileInput.files[0];

            //var blogFile = $("#blogImages")[0];
            //var blogImages = blogFile.files[0];
            var editor = new Quill('#editor');
            var content = editor.getContents();

            var BlogData =
            {

                Title: $(".txttitle").val(),
                DestinationId: $("#ddlDesignation").val(),
                Category: $("#ddlCategory").val(),
                Author: $(".txtauthor").val(),
                AuthorDetail: $(".txtauthorDetail").val(),
                Date: $(".txtDate").val(),
                Contents: content
            }

            var CreateEditBlogsViewModel =
            {
                BlogDTO: BlogData
            }

            var param = JSON.stringify(CreateEditBlogsViewModel);

            //doing ajax request
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json",
                method: "POST",
                dataType:"JSON",
                url: "@Url.Action("Create", "Blog")",
                data: param,
                success: function () {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

In my **Controller**:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(CreateEditBlogsViewModel BlogDTO,IFormFile authorimage,IFormFile images)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _blogservice.Insert(BlogDTO.BlogDTO);
        }

        //rebinding values
        BlogDTO.DestinationSelectList = GetDestinationSelectList();
        BlogDTO.BlogCategorySelectList = GetBlogCategorySelectList();
        return View();

    }
```

My **Model** looks like this:

```
 public class CreateEditBlogsViewModel
{
    public BlogsDTO BlogDTO { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> DestinationSelectList { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> BlogCategorySelectList { get; set; }
}
```

I have also tried applying [FromBody] in controller,but no luck. I also have to post 2 seperate images also but at first i only want that data then i will try to post image.
Please Help.

> Edit : I have solved this by using CKEditor in place of quill editor and now I am posting all the data using form.

Comment: What is null in your case? The IFormFile (only works with `multipart/form-data`)? `CreateEditBlogsViewModel`? You do seem to miss to jsonfy the object

Comment: Currently i am only working on the data part, I will work on the image part after that. The CreateEditBlogsViewModel is going null, I have also noticed one thing that when i am applying [FromBody] in my controller the whole CreateEditBlogsViewModel  object is showing null but without [FromBody] the object name BlogDTO is not coming null, but the BlogDTO object of CreateEditBlogsViewModel   is showing null, Hope you understood what i have said.

Comment: Well, sending json payload with `application/json` and uploading files with `multipart/form-data` are mutually exclusive. `multipart/form-data` requires the form data to be sent as key/value pairs a la `key=value&key2=value2` while `application/json` tells the server to expect a json payload a `{ "key": "value", "key2": "value2" }`. You can't have both, file upload and json payload

Comment: I just want to post data and images using ajax is there any way to do it.

Comment: For model binding, you need to use `Create([FromBody]CreateEditBlogsViewModel createEditBlogsViewModel)`

Comment: Ajax isn't very suitable neither its very performant when it comes to uploads, because you can't stream it. You to load and parse the whole json file into memory (memory intensive) and encode the images as base 64 (upload size grows by 33%), also you can't start processing the file until its all fully completed. Very very bad choice (performance and design wise)